# SQL Server: Using Case in FUNCTION

Tags: sql-server, function, case

New to SQL, seasoned VBA-er in need of some assistance.

I have a View on transactions that requires to get some different fees of specific types. The fees are in a table where some fields are required and others might be NULL. This way we can get a general fee structure set up and still allow for specific specials.

My goal now is to find the best matching fee. This is the fee which:

1. Matches all required criteria,
2. Matches all optional criteria OR has `NULL` for them,
3. Has the most matching optional criteria of all fees that pass 1. and 2.

Now I got a version of this code working but as a PROCEDURE. However as I need this to be used in a view I can't use that version and there are no temp tables allowed in a function).

After looking on this forum and others I came to a result that still gives 2 errors:
  1. ErrorMessage: Incorrect syntax near `'@tblTEMP'`,
  2. ErrorMessage: Incorrect syntax near `'BEGIN'`.

My current script is as follows (using a local variable table):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnStandardFeeBAK]
  (@Type_Id BIGINT, @Party_Id BIGINT, @I_A_Id BIGINT, @Grid_Id BIGINT,
  @Market_Id BIGINT, @Counterparty_Id BIGINT, @Product_Id BIGINT, 
  @DealDate DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE

AS

BEGIN
  DECLARE @tblTEMP TABLE (Standard_Fee DECIMAL(38,8), Currency VARCHAR(50), 
  Unit VARCHAR(50), Unit2 VARCHAR(50), MatchScore BIGINT);
  WITH @tblTEMP AS 
  (SELECT Standard_Fee, V2.Element AS Currency, V1.Element AS Unit,
V2.Element+'/'+V1.Element AS Unit2,
  SF.I_A_Id, SF.Grid_Id, SF.Product_Id, SF.Counterparty_Id,
  (CASE WHEN SF.I_A_Id = @I_A_Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN SF.Grid_Id = @Grid_Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN SF.Product_Id = @Product_Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN SF.Counterparty_Id = @Counterparty_Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      AS MatchScore
  FROM tblStandard_Fee AS SF
  LEFT JOIN tblElement AS V1 ON V1.Element_Id = SF.Unit_Id
  LEFT JOIN tblElement AS V2 ON V2.Element_Id = SF.Currency_Id

  WHERE SF.Type_Id = @Type_Id AND SF.Party_Id = @Party_Id AND 
    SF.Market_Id = @Market_Id
    AND SF.Date_From < @DealDate 
    AND (SF.Date_To > @DealDate OR SF.Date_To IS NULL)
    AND (SF.I_A_Id = @I_A_Id OR SF.I_A_Id IS NULL)
    AND (SF.Grid_Id = @Grid_Id OR SF.Grid_Id IS NULL)
    AND (SF.Product_Id = @Product_Id OR SF.Product_Id IS NULL)
    AND (SF.Counterparty_Id = @Counterparty_Id OR SF.Counterparty_Id IS NULL))
RETURN
  SELECT Standard_Fee, Currency, Unit, Unit2
  FROM @tblTEMP
  WHERE MatchScore= MAX(MatchScore)
END
```

I hope my problem is clear if not let me know.

Thank you for making suggestions or even solving my issue with this last bit!

---

So all of LittleBobbyTables' help combined gave me a working end result. Please dont forget to give him credits for this.

Working code:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnStandardFeeBAK]
(@Type_Id BIGINT, @Party_Id BIGINT, @I_A_Id BIGINT, @Grid_Id BIGINT,
@Market_Id BIGINT, @Counterparty_Id BIGINT, @Product_Id BIGINT, @DealDate DATETIME)

RETURNS @YourTable TABLE 
(
    -- Columns returned by the function
    Standard_Fee DECIMAL(38,8), 
    Currency VARCHAR(50), 
    Unit VARCHAR(50), 
    Unit2 VARCHAR(50)
)
AS

BEGIN   
    WITH YourCTE(Standard_Fee, Currency, Unit, Unit2, MatchScore) AS
    (
    SELECT Standard_Fee, V2.Element AS Currency, V1.Element AS Unit,
        V2.Element + '/' + V1.Element AS Unit2,
        (CASE WHEN SF.I_A_Id = @I_A_Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN SF.Grid_Id = @Grid_Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN SF.Product_Id = @Product_Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN SF.Counterparty_Id = @Counterparty_Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        AS MatchScore
    FROM tblStandard_Fee AS SF
        LEFT JOIN tblElement AS V1 ON V1.Element_Id = SF.Unit_Id
        LEFT JOIN tblElement AS V2 ON V2.Element_Id = SF.Currency_Id

    --Type_ID, Party_ID and Market_Id are always present, others can have NULL values
    WHERE SF.Type_Id = @Type_Id AND SF.Party_Id = @Party_Id 
            AND SF.Market_Id = @Market_Id AND SF.Date_From < @DealDate 
            AND (SF.Date_To > @DealDate OR SF.Date_To IS NULL)
            AND (SF.I_A_Id = @I_A_Id OR SF.I_A_Id IS NULL)
            AND (SF.Grid_Id = @Grid_Id OR SF.Grid_Id IS NULL)
            AND (SF.Product_Id = @Product_Id OR SF.Product_Id IS NULL)
            AND (SF.Counterparty_Id = @Counterparty_Id OR SF.Counterparty_Id IS NULL)
    GROUP BY Standard_Fee, V1.Element, V2.Element, SF.I_A_Id, SF.Grid_Id, SF.Product_Id, SF.Counterparty_Id
    )
    INSERT @YourTable 
        SELECT Standard_Fee, Currency, Unit, Unit2
        FROM YourCTE 
        GROUP BY MatchScore, Standard_Fee, Currency, Unit, Unit2
        HAVING MatchScore = (SELECT MAX(MatchScore) FROM YourCTE)

     RETURN;
END
```

Comment: I now see I have `SF.I_A_Id, SF.Grid_Id, SF.Product_Id, SF.Counterparty_Id,` still in my code in the first select statement. However even taking that out will not get rid of the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Table-Valued User-Defined Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) documentation, the correct syntax is:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnStandardFeeBAK(@Type_Id BIGINT, @Party_Id BIGINT, 
    @I_A_Id BIGINT, @Grid_Id BIGINT,  @Market_Id BIGINT, 
    @Counterparty_Id BIGINT, @Product_Id BIGINT, 
    @DealDate DATETIME)

RETURNS @YourTable TABLE 
(
    -- Columns returned by the function
    Standard_Fee DECIMAL(38,8), 
    Currency VARCHAR(50), 
    Unit VARCHAR(50), 
    Unit2 VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
```

And at the end:

```
    INSERT @YourTable 
    SELECT Standard_Fee, Currency, Unit, Unit2
    FROM YourCTE
    WHERE MatchScore= MAX(MatchScore)
    RETURN;
END;
```

**EDIT**:  Messed up the CTE, you don't need the temp table.

Throw it all together, and you get:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnStandardFeeBAK(@Type_Id BIGINT, @Party_Id BIGINT, 
    @I_A_Id BIGINT, @Grid_Id BIGINT,  @Market_Id BIGINT, 
    @Counterparty_Id BIGINT, @Product_Id BIGINT, 
    @DealDate DATETIME)

RETURNS @YourTable TABLE 
(
    -- Columns returned by the function
    Standard_Fee DECIMAL(38,8), 
    Currency VARCHAR(50), 
    Unit VARCHAR(50), 
    Unit2 VARCHAR(50)
)
AS

BEGIN
 WITH YourCTE (Standard_Fee, Currency, Unit, Unit2, MatchScore) AS 
  (SELECT Standard_Fee, V2.Element AS Currency, V1.Element AS Unit,
V2.Element+'/'+V1.Element AS Unit2,
  SF.I_A_Id, SF.Grid_Id, SF.Product_Id, SF.Counterparty_Id,
  (CASE WHEN SF.I_A_Id = @I_A_Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN SF.Grid_Id = @Grid_Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN SF.Product_Id = @Product_Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN SF.Counterparty_Id = @Counterparty_Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      AS MatchScore
  FROM tblStandard_Fee AS SF
  LEFT JOIN tblElement AS V1 ON V1.Element_Id = SF.Unit_Id
  LEFT JOIN tblElement AS V2 ON V2.Element_Id = SF.Currency_Id

  WHERE SF.Type_Id = @Type_Id AND SF.Party_Id = @Party_Id AND 
    SF.Market_Id = @Market_Id
    AND SF.Date_From < @DealDate 
    AND (SF.Date_To > @DealDate OR SF.Date_To IS NULL)
    AND (SF.I_A_Id = @I_A_Id OR SF.I_A_Id IS NULL)
    AND (SF.Grid_Id = @Grid_Id OR SF.Grid_Id IS NULL)
    AND (SF.Product_Id = @Product_Id OR SF.Product_Id IS NULL)
    AND (SF.Counterparty_Id = @Counterparty_Id OR SF.Counterparty_Id IS NULL))

  INSERT @YourTable 
    SELECT Standard_Fee, Currency, Unit, Unit2
    FROM YourCTE
    WHERE MatchScore= MAX(MatchScore)
  RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: The second error is surely gone with these changes, thank you for that!  Unfortunately I am still left with an error on the local variable TABLE.   It gets related to the line `With @tblTEMP AS`

Comment: @K_B - I removed the temp table, and created a standard CTE.

Comment: I have applied that and also took out the excess items in line `SF.I_A_Id, SF.Grid_Id, SF.Product_Id, SF.Counterparty_Id,` however it now gives the error: `ErrorMessage: An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.`

Comment: The mentioned new ErrorMessage is related to the line `WITH YourCTE(Standard_Fee, Currency, Unit, Unit2, MatchScore) AS`

Comment: The problem is this line:  `WHERE MatchScore= MAX(MatchScore)`.  Try `HAVING MatchScore= MAX(MatchScore)`

Comment: I altered that, and added the Group By for all the vairables. Then I got a specific error on the top part (where I add up the `Case` results) and had to add Group By there as well. It all works now. I'll post the end result!

Comment: THANK YOU LittleBobbyTables!!